# Как сделать висящее в трее приложение?

Tags: android, java

Хочу понять, как сделать приложение висящее в памяти, опрашивающее изменения на сервере (новые сообщения и т.д.) и сообщающие об этом в верхней строке устройства?

Как, кликая по строке оповещения открывать приложение?
Как вообще эта схема работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://habrahabr.ru/post/140928/

Answer (score 5):

Вообще-то эта штука называется `Notification`. Достаточно внятно об этом можно [прочитать здесь](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html) или [тут](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html).

Если совсем кратко, то это в общем некая компонента приложения независимая от жизненного цикла `Activity` обладающая собственными вьюшками (`RemoteView`) и позволяющая запускать подобия интентов (`PendingIntent`).